# How do I resize an OpenGL texture created using new DSA?

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

My texture class uses new function `glTextureStorage2d()` (which OpenGL recommends), but the problem here is that this function makes the texture size immutable, unlike the old `glTexImage2d()`. I'm making a photo-viewer app, so how do I reset the texture data to another image with different dimensions?

Comment: You create a new texture.

Comment: ... which is the same thing your graphics driver was doing before, by the way. Every time you changed the size, it was making a new texture and deleting the old one.